# Secure live wire - 3 wires cut at same length still in sheathing

Tags: wiring

Wire coming in from electrical box (120V) - 3 wires, black, white, ground, all together in their sheathing, not stripped. Have been cut all at the same length (together).

My understanding is that live wires should be secured through a wire nut with  electrical tape. But, is there another way to secure the wires that are not stripped that I might not know about? Some other type of cap? Plastic? Or is there a dangers that because the wires have been cut the open wires are too close together so could produce a short (e.g. white and black touching)?

Comment: Aside: a proper wire nut for two or more wires doesn't need tape. If the nut is correct the tape is not needed. If the tape is needed, the wire nut is not solid enough.

Answer (score 11):

### That is not allowed to exist.

Every cable must terminate in a junction box.  The junction box cover must remain accessible forever without use of tools.

The cable must have enough length inside the junction box so there is at least 6" past where the sheath is split open.  The wires must go at least 3" beyond the wall or ceiling surface (so you don't need finger gymnastics to attach wires to a device).

Thus, the problem is easily solved by splitting the sheath and separating the wires.  Then you can cap them with wire nuts and tape them on.

If you're not willing to terminate the loose end in a junction box right now (e.g. you have down-lights on order), then real simple: Disconnect the other end of the cable so it is NOT energized.  Again, that splice must be in a junction box that remains accessible forever, so it's no inconvenience.

### Capping off wires using wire nuts.

When capping off a single wire, people get two things wrong.  First, they use nuts that are *far too large!* They usually have the yellow, red or tan nuts, if you actually read the [UL approval sheet](https://www.idealind.com/content/dam/electrical/assets/WireTermination/P-5560%20IDEAL%20UL%20Approved%20Wire%20Combination%20Listing03.05.21.pdf) for the nuts, those are like 3 sizes too large to cap a single wire.  So we've been doing it wrong all along; that's why the nuts fall off a single wire and you have to tape them LOL.

So you might as well leave the insulation on the individual wires, they will be a better fit for the normal yellow/red/tan wire nuts.  Still fold them over and still tape them, to make sure the nut can't slide off.

But again, you can't be burying that in a wall and leaving it energized.  If you can't put it into a junction box right now, you need to disconnect the other end from energy source. Hot(s) AND neutral. Neutral is hot too sometimes, that's why it wears insulation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. These wires were for above cabinet lights, and come straight out from the drywall , through a hole. Based on what you're saying I think this was done incorrectly and I should install a junction box and then cap them off?

Comment: You can't have regular AC (120V or 240V) wires coming straight through drywall. They need to be in a junction box. However, in some cases the light fixture will provide a junction box, and it is also possible to rough in the wires without boxes as long as you add them later. But in *all* those cases, do not connect the other (breaker panel) end until the other end is safely in a junction box. If you use low voltage (e.g., 12V) then it is a different situation.

Comment: Even if someone wanted to ignore a blatant violation of the code, leaving a cable cut like this energized would still be a spectacularly bad idea. When the time comes to wire a device in, how would one go about stripping the wires when they're just millimetres from each other and energized?

Comment: @TooTea - you would just cut the power at the breaker if you wanted to reconnect the wires.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - So the wires were coming out of the wall, for about 12 inches, and going into a ballast enclosure for tube lighting. I don't need those lights anymore, so I wanted to remove them, but didn't know what the proper way was to make the wires save. They are on top of cabinets, 10 ft high. I thought just wire nuts to cap them off, wouuld be sufficient, but I think you're saying I would have to also add a junction box?

Comment: @ColinG - The enclosures for some fixtures are approved & listed to be the junction box - so as long as the original fixture was one of those then having the wires come straight out of the wall and into the fixture/j-box it was code-compliant. If/when you install a new fixture you need to either make sure the new one is similarly constructed *and listed* to be its own j-box, or you'll need to but a j-box in the wall where the wires come out.

Comment: @ColinG well, there should've been a box behind that light.  Follow the cable to the other end and disconnect it there.  Or 99 cent steel handy-box, 20 cent cable clamp, 5 cent ground screw.  Attach ground wire to ground screw.   You shouldn't be lopping off the whole cable anyway, disconnect the wire ends inside the lamp to preserve wire length.

Comment: The good news such as it is I think is probably that since the tops of 10 foot cabinets aren't going to be visible.  Meaning you can get away with whatever the least effort box is.  Presumably this would be a surface mount box of the sort you'd normally use when installing new wiring on a solid masonry wall and can't use a normal recessed box.  Thus sparing you from having to cut a hole in the wall to minimize the visual impact like if the wire ends were somewhere lower.

Answer (score 2):

In general cutting and capping a whole cable at once is a bad idea, for a couple of reasons.

1. Cutting is often a messy process, the cable as a whole may be crushed by the cutter. Particuarly with fine-stranded wire, stray strands of wire may be pushed out of positition.
2. Creepage and clearance distances are often significantly larger that required thicknesses for solid insulation. So, even if the cut was perfectly clean the insulation being sufficiently thick does not imply that the bare ends of the wires are far enough apart.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's exactly what I wanted to know and was afraid could happen just looking at the cut, that the individual wires can get too close anyway, and you've confirmed that that  cannot be done safely.

Comment: I cut 12/2, 12/3, 14/2, 14/3 cable with my linesman's pliers all the time without leaving a messy cut or crushing wires. Granted, this is solid wire, but the only time you'll find stranded wire in a bundle in an external sheathing is in cordage, not in cable. The OP is talking about cable here, not cordage.

Answer (score 0):

You must strip the wires before a wire nut will work properly.  So unless you have a 3-at-once wire stripper, which I have never seen, you will need to strip them individually.

Comment: right, before installing a wire nut, you have to strip the wire.  But, is there another way to secure the wires that are not stripped that I might not know about? Some other type of cap? Plastic? Or is there a dangers that because the wires have been cut the open wires are too close together so could produce a short (e.g. white and black touching)?

Comment: These are insulated wires.  They can be in contact with each other as long as the insulation is intact.

Comment: Yes, they are, but when you cut all 3 of them together, at the same time, the cut is not perfect (could make the end widen a bit), and it almost appears that the ends (of the white and black) could be too close together. N

Comment: A three at once stripper on live wires should be fun( for the people watching).

Comment: @ColinG  That is why you put wire nuts on each wire, so the ends never touch.  You are doing this with the power to the wire is off, right?

Comment: @crip659 - Lol, no I do it on live wires, while taking a shower.

Comment: @crip659 So the only proper way to secure live wires (3 of them together in sheeting), cut at the same length) is to strip them and use wire nuts? Maybe I should have phrased the question this way :)

Comment: @ColinG  For live wires that will still have power to/in them, yes.  Can also remove the wire from the breaker box completely or remove/pull the wires out.  You want to protect the person who sucks their thumb and then places over the end of the wires.